# why php-fpm (nginx) takes much RAM memory?

Tags: performance, nginx, amazon-ec2, server, php

My server detail is in screenshot which is best dedicated server from AWS Amazon EC2. 
[image]

But one thing i notice that php-fpm take memory 10.9 GB which is 70% of total. it shouldn't be take much memory like that. am i doing some thing wrong in nginx.conf file ?

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  3000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}




http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    open_file_cache max=20000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid 60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    # keepalive_requests 300;
    # reset_timedout_connection on;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  30;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

}

Comment: You're doing something wrong in your php scripts. Nginx has nothing to do with it.

Comment: show your php-fpm.conf. I bet you have too many pools allowed.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found to make it a little bit down, Change the value of pm = dynamic to pm=ondemand in the php-fpm config file. For php 7 the path is /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf. Don't forget to restart php-fpm after change.